# F11key of IntelliJ idea equivalent in MyEclipse

Tags: editor, intellij-idea, myeclipse

I used to use IntelliJ IDEA as my development environment and I have recently started to use MyEclipse.

In IntelliJ, pressing the <kbd>F11</kbd> key toggles a bookmark. IntelliJ creates a *tic* or a *correct mark* to the left side of the editor and a black icon in right side of editor to indicate that the line is bookmarked.

Pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>F11</kbd> then presents a list of your bookmarks enabling another means of navigating around the codebase.

Does `MyEclipse` have similar functionality and if it does how do I use it?

Answer (score 1):

The following blog entry discusses Bookmark functionality in Eclipse not MyEclipse.

It includes the alternative strategy of adding a `// TODO` comment to the code which will place that in the the Tasks view but in a collaborative project I would think it better to leave **TODO** comments for tasks arising out of incurred technical debt and future code re-factoring.

http://www.luisdelarosa.com/2005/02/16/eclipse-tip-use-bookmarks-to-track-important-places-in-your-code/

Comment: Great tip, Rob. Note that MyEclipse is eclipse with a bunch of good plug-ins, so that works in MyEclipse also.